# Array index does not respond to strict equality when using for...in loop

Tags: javascript

This is a strange behavior that I've encountered today. But I cannot understand why it happens.

```
for (let x in [1]) {
    console.log(x === 0) // false
    console.log(x == 0) // true
}
```

The code snippet should be self explanatory. On the first log we have `strict equality` and on the next one we have `loose equality`. Why are they returning different results? Aren't numbers of the same value equal no matter how we're comparing them?

P.S: This problem doesn't exist if you're using array functions such as `forEach()` and `map()` for iteration

```
[1].forEach((_, i) => {
    console.log(i === 0) // true
    console.log(i == 0) // true
})
```

Comment: Object keys are always of type `string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[1]` is equivalent to `{0: 1}`

When you use `for..in`, it iterates through object's properties (keys). While keys are all in string, so it iterates through `['0']`

So

```
'0' === 0 // false
```

```
'0' == 0 // true
```

could be easily understand since then

Comment: Also I would like to note that if you're using array functions such as `forEach()` and `map()` then the index will be of type number. :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `x` is not a number because `for ... in` iterates over object keys:

```js
for (let x in [1]) {
    console.log(typeof x);
    console.log(x === 0) // false
    console.log(x == 0) // true
}
```

For arrays, you should be using `for ... of`:

```js
for (let x of [1]) {
    console.log(typeof x);
    console.log(x === 0) // false
    console.log(x == 0) // false
}
```